# react js bootstrap response to changes in screen resolution or browser window resizing

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I was got a row of buttons I like to adjust to changes in screen resolution or browser window resizing. Right now, when I change the screen resolution or browser window size, the button starts to overlap to the second row. I read that bootstrap and adjust the size of the buttons or text to handle the changes.

I read another post and added the following code but its not quite working

```
<Grid fluid={true}>
  <Row">
    <Col md={3}>
      <Button ...>
    </Col> 
    <Col md={3}>
      <Button ...>
    </Col> 
    <Col md={3}>
      <Button ...>
    </Col> <Col md={3}>
      <Button ...>
    </Col> 
  </Row>
</Grid>
```

When I resize the screen View from 100% and below, the buttons are resizing in height and all buttons stays on the same row. However, when I change the view resizing with Ctrl + mouse wheel to over 100%, the buttons overlap to the next line. I also see the button row overlap when resizing the browser window size.

Is there a way to resize the buttons when over 100% and changing the browser window size?

I tried to add max-width: 90% !important in the css styling, but that did not work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: wrap every button inside `<div className="col-md-12">`

Comment: what's your desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use react-bootstrap Grid system like this:
This behaviour will make sure that the Columns (aka your buttons in this case) to flow `automatically` when there is no space left, they will start from next line and not overlap as you have now:

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap' 

...

<Container>
  <Row>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
    <Col xs='auto'><Button ... /></Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Or if you're only using css:

```
<div className='container'>
   <div className='row'>
      <div className='col'><Button ... /></div>
      <div className='col'><Button ... /></div>
      <div className='col'><Button ... /></div>
      <div className='col'><Button ... /></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The container element is very helpful. I added to the code but need to refine it somemore. Thanks.

Comment: glad i could help, can you flag it as the correct answer? thanks @user1250264